# Hard vs Soft Deletes on an sports/gaming results application

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am developing a system that will essentially log results for a local sports club, data will consist of results, teams, matches, players that type of thing.

I just wondered what the generally consensus of what is the best solution for the database design and how I handle 'deleted' entries in the database, my choices are as follows:

1. Hard Delete - e.g the db entry is removed (and any related cascaded rows)
2. Soft Delete - use a 'deleted_timestamp' flag - if this has a timestamp value it is considered **deleted** and nobody can see this entry (except myself with direct access to the DB via cPanel to allow for easy recovery of a row)
3. Archived Table - once an entry is removed using a **hard delete** from the main table, I will push this entry into an archive_table with the associated primary_key from the original table.

What do people think are the pro's and cons and based on my scenario what is the preferred solution?

Comment: Depends on your use case. Do you expect to need to recover records, or to have an audit trail of deleted items?

Comment: Option 3 is rarely a good idea; option 2 is more typical, and doesn't preclude using Option 1 on records that have been "deleted" for some length of time (_giving you a "Recycle Bin" of sorts_).

Comment: @ceejayoz i suppose I would need some trail of sorts..
e.g lets say Team Blue has 100 results, and then one day decide to disband. I would want to delete the team however I still want all of their results as they will relate to other teams so need to retain that info. (Does that make sense?)

I am thinking a soft-delete atm

Comment: @Zabs I'm not sure the disbanding of a team should warrant even soft deletion, especially if there is data still tying them to active teams. You are better off with a disbanded_when field, and a process run intermittently to flag teams for soft deletion when they have nothing tied to "active data".

Comment: Should 'opinion based' questions like this be added somewhere else in StackExchange?

Comment: @Zabs Maybe http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, but read their rules first. I'm not familiar enough with them to know if it'd be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hard Delete**

**Pros:**

-The easiest to implement

-No system overhead (HDD space, execution time, code complexity)

**Cons:**

-Data is gone forever

**Soft Delete**

**Pros:**

-Data is not gone forever

-Data can be easlily managed as if was not deleted (maybe to let admins see the old entries and revert deletion, or stuffs like that. the data is still in the same table where it originally was)

**Cons:**

-Costly to maintain the code? in every query you should remember where to filter the deleted data and where not to

-Tables may grow hugely, decreasing query performance drastically

**Archived:**

**Pros:**

-Data is not gone forever

-Tables containing the non-deleted data will be kept small and clean like in Hard Delete solution

**Cons:**

-Hard to manage the archived data as the current data (for example, a query to display both deleted and not deleted entries ordered by some value requires extra code to be done compared to the soft delete)

That's what i can think about in 5 minutes. There are surely other points that i'm missing

*Edit: i think soft delete suits your need best, as no heavy calculations are involved*